# country drop down not being populate with data codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

country drop down not being populate with data codeigniter, can any body help me out, i want list of country on view so that i could select country. when i add select code in view for drop down it hides the list and save button.

my model

```
public function get_Country() {
        $this->db->select('code, name')->from("country");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

my controller

```
public function get_Country() {
        $ctry = $this->job_post_model->get_Country();
       // debug($ctry);
    }
```

my view code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="about-heading">

            <div class="head-menu"> &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-section">
            <div class="about-content rigs-content">
                <form name="jobpost" action=" <?php echo base_url('employer/job_post/post_job'); ?>" method="post">
                    <h2>Your Job Detail :</h2>

                    <div class="invest-form">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Category:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobcat" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Category*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobtitle" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Title*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Job Type:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="jobtype" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Preffered Age:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="age" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Title*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Preffered Gender:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="gender" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Job Description:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="desc" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Type*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Location:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="location" value="" placeholder="Enter the Country*"  />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Post Code:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="post" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="postcode" placeholder="Enter the City*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Salary:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="salaries" name="salary" placeholder="Enter the Salary*" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <li>
                                <label>Qualification:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="qualification" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="qualification" placeholder="Enter Benifits*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Category:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="category" class="span12" required name="category" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                                <label>Benifits:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="benefits" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" name="benefits" placeholder="Enter Benifits*" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Job Tags:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="jobtags" class="span12" required name="jobtag" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                            <li class="pull-right">
                                <label>Career Level:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="career" class="span12" required name="career" placeholder="Enter Job Tags" />

                            </li>
                          <li>  
                            <label>Country:</label>
                    <?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>
                    <select name="country">
                        <option>Select your country*</option>
                        <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $country->name ?>" </option>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                        </li>    
                            <li class="pull-right">                              
                                <table id="question">

                                    <th>Add Killer Questions</th>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="questions" name="question[]"/></td>


                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                                <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="insertTextBox()" value="Add More"></input></td>
                            </li>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Save As Draft" class="button-next" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="wid-social">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script>  


    var index = 1;
    function insertTextBox(){
            var text = document.getElementById("question");
                var row=text.insertRow(text.rows.length);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var t1=document.createElement("input");
                    t1.id = "question"+index;
                    t1.name = "question[]";
                    cell1.appendChild(t1);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
          index++;  
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you loading the view file?

Comment: by writing this line in url : http://localhost/ajobis/employer/job_post/post_job

Comment: I mean in controller. Nice answer though :)

Comment: Your aren't closing your option opening tag add a > after ?>". Also you're returning countries as an array but accessing its keys as if it were an object. And you should be loading them in the controller then passing to the view

Comment: the way you are calling controller in view is `not correct` and its not a good practice too. you must populate data first and then pass it to your view.

Comment: Firstly, turn on [error reporting](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Because as @xd6_ pointed out, you are accescing an `array` like an object, and you should have gotten an error.

Comment: add  <option value='0'>Select your country*</option>

Answer (score 0):

In model:

Repalce

> return $query->result_array();

With

> return $query->result();

In View :

Repalce

> ```
>  <?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>
>  <select name="country">
>        <option>Select your country*</option>
>            <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
>             <option value="<?php echo $country->name ?>" </option>
>       <?php }
>        ?>
>   </select>
> ```

With

> ```
>  <?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>
>  <?php echo form_dropdown('country',$countries, 0,'required'); ?>
> ```

In Codeigniter Use Codeigniter From Dropdown

Comment: Hi Guarav thanks for your help. if i remove this line "<?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>" its showing empty drop down, otherwise it is not showing anything. can u help me plz. i have done all the changes in model and view

Comment: In codeginter, In controller You have to save this $countries = $this->get_Country();

Comment: Then pass this parameter to the view $data['countries'] = $countries

Comment: then load view with this parameter $this->load->view('view.php', $data);

Comment: then remove this line "<?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>" from view

Answer (score 0):

Your controller didn't `return` anything, so need to modify controller as below.

controller :

```
public function get_Country() {
   return $ctry = $this->job_post_model->get_Country();
}
```

and also your VIEW returning result as an array, you need to use `$country['name']` in the place of `$country->name`.

VIEW:

```
 <?php $countries = get_Country(); ?>
       <select name="country">
             <option>Select your country*</option>
             <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $country['code'] ?>"><?php echo $country['name'] ?></option>
              <?php }
              ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: thanks A.P for your help, but i m sorry i could not under stand as u mentioned that "you need to use $country['name'] in the place of $country->name" this line is don't exists in my model, so can you explain me more please where i would have to change.

Comment: my mistake, i want to say View

Comment: dropdown list is still empty, not populating data. any more idea please ?

Comment: do one thing print_r(countries); in your view and tell are you getting result ?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is correct, but you do need to decide if you are going to access the data as an `array` or an `object`. That will dictate how you access your data in the View.

`$query->result_array()` returns an `array`

`$query->result()` returns an `object`

In your controller you need to use your model.

```
// Load your model into your controller
$this->load->model('your_model');

// use your_model method to set $data['countries']
$data['countries'] = $this->your_model->get_Country();

// You will access $countries in your view by passing it to your view
$this->load->view('your_view'), $data);
```

In your view, if you choose `$query->result()` in your model :

```
<select name="country">
  <option>Select your country*</option>
<?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>             
  <option value="<?php echo $country->name ?>"><?php echo $country->name ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks Brett for your help. i have made all changes as you mentioned in detail, but no data is being populated in list. what can be the reason please ?

Comment: Before you load your view enter the following code:`echo "<pre><code>";
print_r($data);
echo "</code></pre>";
die();`

Comment: Also, 'your_model' needs to be the name of **your** model. Just checking.